# WooCommerce - variable products for all attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am developing an online sales site for a client.
I work on my website online hosting by Godaddy.

I have install the WooCommerce plugin.

I want to add variable products. I already enter the attributes I need. When the time comes to convert its attributes in real variables, using the button create variations for all attributes 95% of the time it does not execute anything.
Nothing append. I don't know what to do.

The button for creating one variation work fine actually. I don't want to enter 312 variations (approximately) one by one. I can make many mistakes.

I see in a forum that deactivated all my plugin (except WooCommerce) work for minimum 2 persons. For me, it does not work.

How can I make my button works all the time?

- Version of WordPress: **4.3.1**
- Version of WooCommerce: **2.4.10**

Comment: To provide help, we would need more detailed information of errors that pop up or something like that. That specific button send AJAX requests to the server. In the network panel of the dev tools you should see what is happening, i.e. if the requests fail or something similar.

Comment: I have no pop up error, no error on the page and with the network panel, when I click to the button, I see admin-ajax.php after 6 seconds nut nothing happen.

Comment: In This case I would guess something is blocking the click on the "go" button, or anything similar to that. As soon as you click that button, you should see outgoing requests to "admin-ajax". I would suggest trying different browsers, or checking if you have a plugin that might block javascript. Also revert to the basic theme and deactivate any plugin apart from woocommerce to check if the error persists.

Comment: I work well on safari. Thank you. I don't know how on Chrome it's not working but I will do it in Safari.